# LSA Weighted Fair Queuing Algorithm

Tags: switch, qos, congestion

In weighted round robin (weighted fair queuing) scheduling, suppose I have 3 queues (weights):- A (4), B (3) and C (2). I have packets of equal lengths on the 3 queues. Now will the packet output order be

1) AABABCABC (found in online sources: http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Weighted_Round-Robin_Scheduling)
or

2) will it be ABCABCABA
or

3) will it be AAAABBBCC

I know it doesn't really affect the throughput per port or anything, just out of curiosity I'm asking. Found different versions in different online sources.

Comment: What does LSA refer to in your title?

Comment: Link Scheduling Algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cisco IOS:

> The order of removal from the fair queues is determined by the virtual
>   time of the delivery of the last bit of each arriving packet.

src: [Cisco IOS Quality of Service Solutions Configuration Guide, Release 12.2](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/qos/configuration/guide/fqos_c/qcfconmg.html#wp1001092)